# Unmarshalling fails with no errors when setting namespace to @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

I have created a **JAXB** object and I am trying to unmarshal an xml string into it. 
The problem that I am facing is that when I put the `namespace` property in the `@XmlRootElement` and in the xml document that I am sending, the **JAXB** object is getting created but it is empty. If I remove the namespace it works. So here is what I mean

**My JAXB Object:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "incident", namespace = "http://www.ba.com/schema/BAserviceDeskAPI/incident")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Incident {

    @XmlElement
    private String eventTitle;

    public Incident() {
    }

    public String getEventTitle() {
        return eventTitle;
    }

    public void setEventTitle(String eventTitle) {
        this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Incident [");
        builder.append("eventTitle=");
        builder.append(eventTitle);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**My Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        String s = "<incident xmlns=\"http://www.ba.com/schema/BAserviceDeskAPI/incident\">"
                + "<eventTitle>Test Title from BAwrapper</eventTitle>"
                + "</incident>";
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Incident.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Incident incident = (Incident) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

        System.out.println(incident.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Incident [eventTitle=null]
```

If I remove the `, namespace = "http://www.ba.com/schema/BAserviceDeskAPI/incident"` from the `@XmlRootElement` and the `xmlns=\"http://www.ba.com/schema/BAserviceDeskAPI/incident\"` from the xml sent I get the output below

`Incident [eventTitle=Test Title from BAwrapper]`

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: When I enter this url http://www.ba.com/schema/BAserviceDeskAPI/incident it says the page you requested can't be found...

Comment: @brso05 Yes it doesn't. Is this the problem? I tested it with a valid URL but still the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the only problem but it sounds like a problem...

Comment: @brso05 - This is no requirement that the value of a namespace be a vaild URL that corresponds to anything.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan that may be true I never said that was his only problem but lets say he fixes his other problem and the schema still isn't working but doesn't throw an error this time that will still be a problem.

Comment: @brso05 - But what you referenced isn't a problem.  A namespace is like a package name it Java, it isn't meant to be a URL to an XML schema.  There is no problem to be fixed with the URI itself.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan ahh I see...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace specified on `@XmlRootElement` only applies to that element.  If you want it to apply to all the elements you have mapped to, you can do it at the package level using the `@XmlSchema` annotation.

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.ba.com/schema/BAserviceDeskAPI/incident", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about JAXB and namespace qualification on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

### Additional Info

> Unmarshalling fails with no errors when setting namespace to
>   @XmlRootElement

For JAXB we (the JSR-222 expert group) decided that an unmarshal shouldn't fail by default if there is unmapped content.  Why?  Because alot of XML documents contain extra content and things would be failing all the time.  If you do want to see these errors then you can specify a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller`.

Comment: @NikosDim - Happy to hear everything worked.  I have updated my answer to address why you weren't seeing any errors.