# JAXB XSD namespace unmarshal return null

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I want to map a xml file into the Java Object. I have a schema to validate the xml.

Java class

```
Schema schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(
                new File("src/PersonDetails.xsd"));
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
Person response = (Person ) unmarshaller.unmarshal(newFileInputStream("src/PersonDetails.xml"));
System.out.println(response.getPersonNo());
```

PersonDetails.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    version="1-0-20101115" id="PersonDetails">
    <xs:element name="PersonDetails">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PersonNo" nillable="false">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="30" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

PersonDetails.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonDetails xmlns="http://www.example.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com PersonDetails_v1-0-20101115.xsd">
    <PersonNo>PERS-0001-000001</PersonNo>
</PersonDetails>
```

Person.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PersonDetails", namespace="http://www.example.com")
public class Person {
  private String personNo;

  @XmlElement(name = "PersonNo")
  public String getPersonNo(){
     return personNo;
  }
}
```

The personNo return null. If I removed the namespace and the xmlns declaration from xsd and xml I can get the correct value.

When I tried to Marshall using the same schema, I got this error:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'PersonNo'. One of '{"http://www.example.com":PersonNo}' is expected.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:35)
```

Comment: newFileInputStream("src/PersonDetails.xml") this stream is not null right?

Comment: Ya confirm not null, if I remove namespace, xmlns all those declaration I am able to get the data. I try using StringReader also the same

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem.I through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508037/unmarshalling-fails-with-no-errors-when-setting-namespace-to-xmlrootelement) solved the problem.

The solution is to create a package-info.java file, using the @XmlSchema annotation on the package.

**package-info.java**

```xml
XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.ba.com/schema/BAserviceDeskAPI/incident", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```